# Android Architecture Component ViewModel - How to mock ViewModel on test Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to setup UI testing similar to **GithubBrowserSample** and it looks like the sample project only has mock `ViewModel` for `Fragment` but not an example for `Activity`.

Here's my code where I am trying to test the `Activity` by mocking `ViewModel`. But the `ViewModel` is not getting set before `onCreate()` in Activity.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    val viewModel = mock(MainViewModel::class.java)

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java, true, true)

    private val liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<Object>>()

    @Before
    open fun setUp() {
        activityRule.activity.viewModelFactory = createViewModelFor(viewModel)
        `when`(viewModel.liveData).thenReturn(liveData)
        viewModel.liveData?.observeForever(mock(Observer::class.java) as Observer<Resource<Object>>)
        liveData.postValue(Resource.success(Object()))
    }

    fun <T : ViewModel> createViewModelFor(model: T): ViewModelProvider.Factory =
        object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(model.javaClass)) {
                    return model as T
                }
                throw IllegalArgumentException("unexpected model class " + modelClass)
            }
        }
}
```

Can someone help me about this issue please?

Comment: Can you also share some bits from activity class?

Answer (score 3):

JUnit `@Rule`s do their setup before `@Before` methods, so your activity is launching and starting its lifecycle before your `setUp()` method gets called. To avoid this, pass `false` as the third parameter to the rule constructor. This tells it not to launch the activity automatically, so you can do your setup in advance.

Then, you need to launch the activity manually before you run your tests. You can create an intent like `val intent = Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.targetContext, MainActivity::class.java)` and then pass it to `activityRule.launchActivity(intent)`.

Comment: I can not do it, because activityRule.activity = null