# Testing Android ViewModelProvider with a mock ViewModel

Tags: android, unit-testing, mvvm

I'm excited to use the new Android Architecture Components ViewModel system, which nicely separates the Activity/Fragment/Layout rendering concerns from the ViewModel logic. I've successfully unit-tested the ViewModel in isolation, and now would like to try out some screenshot testing by providing mocked ViewModels to the Activity/Fragment for various state scenarios.

I've successfully configured my androidTests to be able to use Mockito in my device tests, that part works great.

However, the [officially recommended way](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement) of calling ViewModelProvider or delegating `by viewModels<>` does not seem to offer a way to inject mocked ViewModels. I'd rather not add an entire DI framework just to work around this omission in the documentation, so I wonder if anyone has any successful examples of providing mocked ViewModels with the official Android Architecture Components without the extra dependencies of Dagger or Hilt.

[The only related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988514/android-architecture-component-viewmodel-how-to-mock-viewmodel-on-test-activit) from 1 year ago suggests using `ActivityTestRule` and manually controlling the activity lifecycle, but that Rule is deprecated in favor of `activityScenarioRule` which does not provide this control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to rewrite the `by viewModels` delegate to check for instances in a map of mock ViewModels, so my activities can use the normal delegate pattern and provide their own factories if the ViewModel isn't found.

```
val mockedViewModels = HashMap<Class<*>, ViewModel>()

@MainThread
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> ComponentActivity.viewModels(
        noinline factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = null
): Lazy<VM> {
    // the production producer
    val factoryPromise = factoryProducer ?: {
        defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    }
    return createMockedViewModelLazy(VM::class, { viewModelStore }, factoryPromise)
}
/// ... and similar for the fragment-ktx delegates

/**
 * Wraps the default factoryPromise with one that looks in the mockedViewModels map
 */
fun <VM : ViewModel> createMockedViewModelLazy(
        viewModelClass: KClass<VM>,
        storeProducer: () -> ViewModelStore,
        factoryPromise: () -> ViewModelProvider.Factory
): Lazy<VM> {
    // the mock producer
    val mockedFactoryPromise: () -> ViewModelProvider.Factory = {
        // if there are any mocked ViewModels, return a Factory that fetches them
        if (mockedViewModels.isNotEmpty()) {
            object: ViewModelProvider.Factory {
                override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                    return mockedViewModels[modelClass] as T
                            ?: factoryPromise().create(modelClass)  // return the normal one if no mock found
                }
            }
        } else {
            // if no mocks, call the normal factoryPromise directly
            factoryPromise()
        }
    }

    return ViewModelLazy(viewModelClass, storeProducer, mockedFactoryPromise)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ViewModelProvider`, so you can replace the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` in the tests with a mock. For example by using:

```kotlin
 viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelFactoryOfFactory.INSTANCE)
    .get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Where:

```kotlin
object ViewModelFactoryOfFactory {

    // The default factory.
    var INSTANCE: ViewModelProvider.Factory = MyViewModelFactory()
        private set

    // To set the factory during tests.
    @VisibleForTesting
    fun setTestFactory(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory) {
        ViewModelFactoryOfFactory.INSTANCE = factory
    }
}
```

Then in the tests setup one can:

```
ViewModelFactoryOfFactory.setTestFactory(mockFactory)
```

One may argue that all this could be replaced by just the factory to get the ViewModel.

Another option could be just make the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` a field/property in the Activity or fragment, so it can be also set from tests, also allowing for better memory management.